Covariant formulation of Classical Electrodynamics in presence of magnetic monopole charge and current
I was trying to rewrite the classical covariant formulation of electrodynamics in case there were magnetic monopoles. Letting $J_m^\mu=(c\rho_m,\vec J_m)$ be the magnetic 4-current I get the following modified fields for $\vec E$ and $\vec B$:
$$\vec E=\textbf{curl}(W)-\textbf {grad}(V)-\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}$$
$$\vec B=\textbf{curl}(A)+\textbf {grad}(\phi)+1/c^2\frac{\partial \vec W}{\partial t}$$
where the following conditions are satisfied:
$$\Box A^\mu=\mu_0J_e^\mu$$
$$\Box \psi^\mu=\mu_0J_m^\mu$$
$$\frac{\partial A^\mu}{\partial x^\mu}=\frac{\partial \psi^\mu}{\partial x^\mu}=0$$ (the latter represents the Lorenz Gauge condition)
I defined $$A^\mu=(V/c,\vec A)$$
$$\psi^\mu=(c\phi, \vec W)$$
Now my question: what is the general form of the electromagnetic tensor in this case? I tried to extend the analogy from the case where magnetic charge and current are zero but surely it can't be $F^{\mu v}=\partial ^\mu (A+\psi)^v-\partial ^v (A+\psi)^\mu$ otherwise the dual tensor would be $G^{\mu v}=\epsilon ^{\mu v ab}F_{ab}/2$ and by construction it would yield $\partial _v G^{\mu v}=0$ instead we want  $\partial _v G^{\mu v}=\mu_0 J_m^\mu$. In general I would like to know if there is some reasonable way to know the form of the electromagnetic tensor if the form of the fields is specificed (that is, is there a way to arrive at the correct expression that is more porofund than guessing the right one knowing the fields)?

In the presence of magnetic charges, $\partial_{[\mu} F_{\nu\rho]} \neq 0$ so you simply cannot write $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. In other words, $A_\mu$ does not exist. You have to work directly with $F_{\mu\nu}$. Another way is to work with a $A_\mu$ that is not smooth in spacetime (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_string)

You can view this as an application of the Hodge decomposition theorem in 4D generalisation for 2-forms. It is similar to how Hodge decomposition applied in 3D to vector fields gives the Helmholtz decomposition. Your Faraday tensor, which is a 2-form, can be written generally as:
$$
F = d\alpha+\delta\beta+\gamma
$$
with $\alpha$ the usual 4-vector potential vector, the "electric" 4-vector potential (because it reacts to electric charges) viewed as a 1-form ($d$ is the exterior differential), $\beta$ the "magnetic" 4-vector potential (because it reacts to magnetic charges) viewed as a 3-form ($\delta$ is the codifferential) and $\phi$ is a harmonic 2-form.
You therefore get:
$$
dF = d\delta\beta = j_m \\
\delta F = \delta d\alpha = j_e
$$
with $j_m$ the magnetic 4-current viewed as a 3-form and $j_e$ the electric 4-current viewed as a 1 form. This guarantees the automatic continuity equations:
$$
dj_m = 0 \\
\delta j_e =0
$$
Technically, this holds for closed manifolds, so not for Minkowski spacetime $\mathbb R^4$, but assuming that the fields decay sufficiently fast at infinity, this kind of decomposition still holds.
The pedestrian approach is to view:
$$
F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \alpha_\nu-\partial_\nu \alpha_\mu+\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\partial^\rho \beta^\sigma-\partial^\sigma\beta^\rho)+\gamma_{\mu\nu}
$$
with:
$$
\partial^2\gamma_{\mu\nu} = 0
$$
Intuitively, $\alpha$ is the response to electric charges, $\beta$ to magnetic charges and $\gamma$ free EM waves.

Thanks that was very helpful!
